# Find files modified between two dates on Linux machine

Tags: linux, unix

On Linux/Unix machine how do I find files modified between a certain number of days ago ?
For example say between 2 and 5 days ago, not calendar dates but days ago from right now. So files modified more than 2 days ago, but not more than  5 days days ago. It would not return anything that was modified yesterday, for example.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Actually i would like to do it using find command or combination of commands from unix on the command line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do it on the Unix command line, try using find with the -mtime option.

Example:

```
find /home -iname ".c" -mtime 2 -mtime -4
```

will choose files modified two to four days ago.

Comment: Thanks Gargi for the answer but as i observed and checked, your solution needs a bit correction.
Here is the correction:
         `find /home -iname ".c" -mtime -2 -mtime +4`

Comment: @dheer_krish this is why even trivial edits should be allowed

Comment: Answer and comment are both incorrect; use `find /home -iname ".c" -mtime +2 -mtime -5` to select files modified more than two days ago but less than five days ago.

`-mtime 2 -mtime -4` returns files modified "two days ago".

`-mtime -2 -mtime +4` requires file mod time to both be less than two days ago, and more than four days ago; both cannot be true, so matches zero files.
`date; # Fri Jun 12 18:28:52 MDT 2020; find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 -mtime -5 # ./202006081818.day_08.today-4.txt; # ./202006091818.day_09.today-3.txt`; My example uses maxdepth to prevent recursive search in test.